# What should be considered best practices for this IF loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to check if the sumited link from the user is a img or not. And if it is I want to place it in one img tag. This is my first time using Ruby on rails, or Ruby in general.

```
<% if link.url.include? ".jpg" %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="<%= link.url %>"></img></div>
<% elsif link.url.include? ".png" %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="<%= link.url %>"></img></div>
<% elsif link.url.include? ".gif" %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="<%= link.url %>"></img></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="../assets/no_image.png"></img></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you use Paperclip, take a look at ˋdefault_url` option. Should clean up view and fallback to your default image when no one is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think logic like that belongs into the model, because that makes it easier to test and reuse:

```
# in app/models/link.rb
def image?
  %w( .gif .jpg .png ).include?(File.extname(url))
end

# in the view
<% if link.image? %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="<%= link.url %>"></img></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="../assets/no_image.png"></img></div>
<% end %>
```

Or even shorter (you might want to expend the list of file extensions (e.q. `bmp`, `jpeg` or `tiff`)):

```
# in app/models/link.rb
def image_url
  %w( .gif .jpg .png ).include?(File.extname(url)) ? url : 'no_image.png'
end

# in the view
<div class="img_wrapper"><%= image_tag(link.image_url) %></div>
```

The [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) version will use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
<% img_src = %w(.jpg .png .gif).any? {|e| link.url.include?(e)} ? link.url : "../assets/no_image.png"%>
<div class="img_wrapper"><img src= <%= img_src %> ></img></div>
```

Comment: The `%w(...)` construct splits on whitespace. You don't want commas in there.

Answer (score 1):

Since most of the conditions are the same, you can reduce it into a single condition:

```
<% if [".jpg", ".png", ".gif"].any? { |ext| link.url.ends_with?(ext) %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="<%= link.url %>"></img></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="../assets/no_image.png"></img></div>
<% end %>
```

Note I'm using String#ends_with? from ActiveSupport here, which is included by default in Rails.

It'd probably be more efficient to do the extension check with Regex, though:

```
<% if link.url =~ /.+(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/ %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="<%= link.url %>"></img></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="../assets/no_image.png"></img></div>
<% end %>
```

To explain the Regex:

- the whole thing is wrapped in `//`, which defines it as a regex
- `.+` matches any number of characters
- `(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)` matches any of the extensions.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

So, in plain English: Match a string if it has any number of characters followed by one of the matching extensions followed by the end of the string.

You could refactor it into 2 lines, if you want that:

```
  <% image_url = link.url =~ /.+(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/ ? link.url : "../assets/no_image.png" %>
  <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="<%= image_url %>"></img></div>
```

Comment: @llya sorry typo, its `any?`

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your time. Just wondering is Regex build in?

Comment: @J.Perrone yeah, it's build into Ruby. I recommend [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com) to help learn it.

Comment: I just tested your 2 line version and I got this error: undefined local variable or method `string' for #<#<Class:0x37d75b8>:0x379a508>

Comment: @J.Perrone should be `link.url`

Comment: There is no need for `.+` at the beginning of Regex.